# Keras fit() and fit_generator() give different results

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Keras fit() and fit_generator() gives different results. I implemented both methods keeping all the other parameters same. I have attached my data generator and model below. The model is taken from this site. https://machinelearningmastery.com/

In data generator, I am loading the data from the hard drive. Each X_train file contains a matrix of size (3,1). For example, if the batch size is 2, the size of X_batch will be (2, 3, 1).

```
def generator(list_xtrain, list_ytrain, batch_size):
  samples_per_epoch = len(list_xtrain)
  number_of_batches = samples_per_epoch/batch_size
  counter=0
  X_batch = np.empty((batch_size,3,1))
  y_batch = np.empty((batch_size))

while 1:
  temp_listx = list_xtrain[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
  temp_listy = list_ytrain[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
  for i, ID in enumerate(temp_listx):
       X_batch[i,] = np.load('F:/Air_passenger_data_gen/' + ID)
  for j, ID in enumerate(temp_listy):
        # Store class
       y_batch[j] = np.load('F:/Air_passenger_data_gen/' + ID)
  counter += 1
  yield X_batch,y_batch

#restart counter to yeild data in the next epoch as well
 if counter >= number_of_batches:
    counter = 0
#using fit_generator()
 batch_size=2
 model.fit_generator(generator=generator(list_xtrain, list_ytrain, 
                     batch_size),
                     epochs=100,
                     steps_per_epoch=len(list_xtrain)/batch_size,
                     verbose=2,
                     use_multiprocessing=False,
                     workers=4)
 #using fit()
 model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=2)
```

I expect the output to be same as that from fit(). But using fit_generator() gives some crazy value for loss=41781.00 whereas using fit(), the loss=0.0020

Comment: are your weights randmonly initialized?

Comment: @josoler Did not initialize the weights. The default initialization is used.